# Custom React renderer with async reconciler methods

Tags: reactjs

I am building my own custom React renderer which renders into my own custom engine, not DOM. It works but ideally I want to move my lower engine layer into its own process/webworker. This would however now make all manipulations to the engine require async calls.

Does the `react-reconciler` `HostConfig` support asynchronous methods? If so, to what extent and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try to answer this to the extent of my knowledge, using examples. I am assuming you know the basics of `react-reconciler`.

`react-reconciler` does not support async methods in a conventional way. But;

When a renderer method like `createInstance` is called, reconciler expects an immediate result. But what that result is up to you, as long as it is something unique. It can be an object, pointer, integer, Promise, DOMElement, string. You can use this to your advantage.

For example, let's say you are creating a renderer for browser, that creates a DOMElement after 1 second. Then you would write `createInstance` method like (very simple example):

```
createInstance(type) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(document.createElement(type)), 1000);
  });
}
```

However, note that this promise will be passed to the other reconciler methods. So you will have to write other reconciler methods like:

```
commitUpdate(instance, payload) {
  instance.then((val) => {
    val.attribute = payload; // Do your thing
  });
}
```

Also, `ref` will be passed this promise. Use it like:

```
function App() {
  const [ref, setRef] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    ref.then((el) => {
      el.value = 'Hello world';
    });
  }, [ref]);

  return <input ref={ref} />;
}
```

In my example, I used a Promise. But you can use a pointer (maybe you have a native object), an integer (maybe you have an index in a queue), a string (a hashed key maybe). The only restriction is that it must be unique.

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense, and gives me a few ideas.